# What happens if I don’t have a prerequisite class for a grad school admissions but am in the process of taking them?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

What happens if I don’t have prerequisite classes for grad school admissions but am in the process of taking them. The application deadline for a graduate school I am interested in is December 1, but grades for the two pre-requisite courses I am missing won't be available until December 20th.

Should I tell admissions that I am currently in the process of taking them?

Edit: My school is in the United States.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at your transcripts, which will typically be submitted with your application... In my experience, these include in-progress and registered courses for the current and subsequent semesters.

In the US, it is totally normal for students graduating in spring 2023 to be applying for grad school for fall 2023, with applications due around December 2022. When applications are due, students will typically have all courses they are taking/will take on their transcript as either in-progress or registered for the next semester.

There won't be any need to separately call out these courses as in progress, it'll be obvious and as expected from the transcripts. Possibly you can mention separately your planned enrollment if your institution doesn't include these on transcripts.

If you are admitted for grad school, your admission will likely be contingent on completing your degree and the coursework you planned to complete at the time of application, but it's totally normal and expected that not all requirements for admission (in particular, completing a bachelor's degree) are complete at time of application.

Answer (score 4):

You do not state the country of the school to which you are applying. However, most universities are aware that there are students in your situation. You should provide them with the information that you are currently taking these required classes and, depending on the country, proof of enrollment. The admissions office is the best one to answer this question.